# JQuery Each Iterator Skipping Count and Not Replacing Name Field

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use the `.each()` jQuery method to iterate over each of the present input checkbox fields with a class of `input.member-tag-checkbox` and replace the placeholder value of [0] with the updated count. While I feel like I should have the accurate code to do this, I have one problem where the counter is replacing every other value and the other problem is I have only been able to get the counter working with `console.log`, but I can't replace the element value on the fly.

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<div class="member-tag-container">
    <ul class="list-group checked-list-box">
        {{#each member}}
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <p><input type="checkbox" class="member-tag-checkbox" name="memberTag[0]" value="{{this.userIdHash}}">{{this.firstName}} {{this.lastName}} ({{this.email}})</p>
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Here is the jQuery:**

```
//Member count for member tag checkbox input
    var memberFieldName = $('input.member-tag-checkbox')[0].name.replace('[0]', '');
    var memberPlaceholder = $('input.member-tag-checkbox')[0].placeholder;
    var memberCounter = 1;
    $('input.member-tag-checkbox').each(function(){
        console.log($(this)[0].name.replace('[0]', '[' + memberCounter++ + ']'));
        $(this)[0].name.replace('[0]', '[' + memberCounter++ + ']');
    });
```

**Here is the current console output:**

```
memberTag[1]
memberTag[3]
memberTag[5]
memberTag[7]
...
```

**I am looking for:**

```
memberTag[0]
memberTag[1]
memberTag[2]
memberTag[3]
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You increase the value of `memberCounter` twice - first in the `console.log` and after that in the line after.

Option 1 - remove the `console.log` and have only the line that you need.
Option 2 - use two variables.

The real issue is that you don't set the value of the element back to what you want.
Currently you only change the string (but not the value of the element).

```js
var memberFieldName = $('input.member-tag-checkbox')[0].name.replace('[0]', '');
var memberPlaceholder = $('input.member-tag-checkbox')[0].placeholder;
var memberCounter = 1;
var _memberCounter = 1;
$('input.member-tag-checkbox').each(function(){
  console.log($(this)[0].name.replace('[0]', '[' + _memberCounter++ + ']'));
  $(this).val($(this).attr('name').replace('[0]', '[' + memberCounter++ + ']'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="member-tag-container">
    <ul class="list-group checked-list-box">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <p><input type="checkbox" class="member-tag-checkbox" name="memberTag[0]" value="a">a</p>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <p><input type="checkbox" class="member-tag-checkbox" name="memberTag[0]" value="b">b</p>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <p><input type="checkbox" class="member-tag-checkbox" name="memberTag[0]" value="c">c</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but your solution `$(this).val($(this).attr('name').replace('[0]', '[' + memberCounter++ + ']'));` is setting a value with the correct incrementing count rather than replacing the name values with the correct count. When I remove `.val()` it doesn't solve the issue

Comment: Could it have anything to do with where the jQuery exists? It is loaded within `$(document).ready()` and I'm curious if using `.each` and `.replace` will run at the proper time before the elements fully load

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the setup with a much simpler setup. For one, I can set a function parameter on the `.each` which will count the amount of elements that match the jQuery selector. This value should be used as the counter. Once this is set up the easiest way to replace the values is with `.attr` and the function parameter. The result of which looks like this:

```
$('input.member-tag-checkbox').each(function(index){
   $(this).attr('name', 'memberTag[' + index + ']');
});
```